# vs2010 dataadapter not allow to add foreign key table procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I Create two sample table and create both tables inserted procedure in MySql.I listed the both procedure and table script below. Now i try to add the procedures using DataAdapter. First Procedure add successfully.But the second procedure return the error.Cannot add or update a child row : a foreign key constraint fails.

```
CREATE TABLE `hd_test` (
  `FLD_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FLD_NAME` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `FLD_ID` (`FLD_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `hd_test1` (
  `FLD_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FLD_NAME` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLD_PARENT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `FLD_PARENT` (`FLD_PARENT`),
  CONSTRAINT `hd_test1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`FLD_PARENT`) REFERENCES `hd_test` (`FLD_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db_helpdesk.SP_HD_TEST;
CREATE PROCEDURE db_helpdesk.`SP_HD_TEST`(
IN NAME VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO HD_TEST(FLD_NAME)VALUES(NAME);
END;


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db_helpdesk.SP_HD_TEST1;
CREATE PROCEDURE db_helpdesk.`SP_HD_TEST1`(
IN NAME VARCHAR(20),
IN PARENT INTEGER)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO HD_TEST1(FLD_NAME,FLD_PARENT)VALUES(NAME,PARENT);
END;
```

## Error

```
Cannot add or update a child row : a foreign key constraint fails..
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: What values are being passed to `SP_HD_TEST1` procedure?

Comment: Not passed the value just add the procedure in dataset only. Dataset-->add table adaptor -->add existing stored procedure-->Now only i got the error..